# Detect current number calling - iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, callkit

I am currently working on an app which should show informations about the current person calling when it is opened during an ongoing phone call.

So, I need to get the phone number of the person that is currently calling me when launching the app. I have read that it is not possible to do that. Is that right, because that would suck.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the app sandbox, it's **not possible** to track the current caller with a third-party application, as it could be a security issue.